# How to line up intger output in custom Android dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am displaying integer data from an SQLite database using a SimpleCursorAdaptor.
Everything shows up but the alignment is all wrong:
[image]

The dialog looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView android:id="@+id/lvwScores"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnOK "
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="OK" android:layout_below="@id/lvwScores">
   </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With the row xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3">
<TableRow >
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableLayout` is a bad choice.  It's inherent fluidity will cause the columns to vary in width based on the content inside of them (although the stretching does minimize some of this), which you have no control over (see below).  Also, the namespace declaration only needs to be on the root element of the XML, not each one ;)

Simplify your row layout drastically by using this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Score"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Score"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Score"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Score"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The combination of `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `layout_weight="1"` on each element tells the system to lay out all four elements, equally spaced (since they have the same weight sum) to fill the row.  I almost always use nested `LinearLayout` in place of `TableLayout` whenever possible (that's all `TableLayout` really is anyway).

Another thing from the row XML you posted: it's not a good idea to set the root element of a list item's layout with `layout_height=fill_parent` like you have in the `RelativeLayout` tag.  Depending on where this layout get's drawn, the layout manager might actually listen to you and one row might end up taking the entire window!

NOTE ABOUT TABLELAYOUT PARAMS:

If you insist on sticking with `TableLayout`, know that you can (and should) omit all the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes from every child of `TableLayout` and `TableRow`.  Those two widgets ignore what you say and set the values of their children to MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT (respectively), so adding them to your code will only serve to confuse you if you think they're supposed to take effect.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

you should specify the `android:gravity` attribute:

```
<TextView android:gravity="right" />
```

more about this: [Android TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29)

**Update:**

I've modified a bit the row.xml layout.

- changed the `TextViews`' width to
  `fill_parent` (they are stretched
  anyway, so it shouldn't do any harm),
  and
- added some attributes to the
  `TableRow` tag

So it looks like:

```
[...]
<TableRow android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Score"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Score"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Score"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Score"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" android:layout_margin="2dp" />
</TableRow>
[...]
```

And the output looks right now:

[image: table row]

Please let me know if this helped (still very embarrassed...)

Comment: :-s well, that's embarrassing... sorry about that!

Comment: Would specifying "android:numeric" make any difference or is that only for input fields?

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't change anything. I really hope, that my update will help.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Will be a few hours since I am expecting visitors any time soon. :)