# Button below a list not showing

Tags: android, listview

I finally managed to get my list to display properly ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662277/how-to-line-up-intger-output-in-custom-android-dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrl9y.jpg)).

Now I am trying to add a button below the list. What happens is that when the list is too big the button doesn't show. 
The list is scrollable but that's it.
Also, the scrollbar covers some of the data.

This is the main XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   <ListView android:id="@+id/lvwScores" android:layout_below="@id/lloPlayerNames"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnOK  "
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_below="@id/lvwScores" android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the one for the rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Score" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Score" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Score" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Score" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried changing the main to a linear layout but that made it even worse! The list looked like it had been on a crash-diet and was super-thin.

---

Tried:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnOK"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   <ListView android:id="@+id/lvwScores" android:layout_above="@id/btnOK" android:layout_below="@id/lloPlayerNames" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and what I get is:
[image]

when I try:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView     android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
   <ListView android:id="@+id/lvwScores" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnOK"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the button before the list and then use the layout_above property on the list element to position it above the button. Also add `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your button.

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnOK"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@id/lvwScores" android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 

  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

   />

<ListView 
   android:id="@+id/lvwScores" 
   android:layout_below="@id/lloPlayerNames"

   android:layout_above="@id/btnOK"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Now the list disappeared completely. All I get is the header and the button. Gonna have to try again tomorrow cos it is the Sabbath soon and I have to go and get ready. :)

Comment: Just tried this again and now it works. Weir. Gonna transfer it to my phone and see.

Answer (score 9):

Following is what I do on a couple of my apps with a ListView or a ScrollView, where I also have a fixed button or LinearLayout of buttons at the bottom.  The "magic" is to set `android:layout_weight="1"` in the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Quotes!" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="My Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Lol this looks like a hack (height AND weight both set) but it sure works, thanks! :)

Comment: It definitely works! And is the best approach for those who want to use LinearLayout! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a attribute `android:below="@id/lvwScores"` to the `Button` in main xml, this will place the `Button` below the `ListView`.

See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) for more about `RelativeLayout`.