# Button not appearing in my Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, listview, button, android-linearlayout

I have a button inside of a LinearLayout that is oriented vertically. Not sure why the button doesn't show up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical">
<com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.stocktwits.activity"

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tlv:normal_height="64dip"
    tlv:grabber="@+id/icon"
    tlv:remove_mode="slideRight"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does it appear if you take out (temporarily) the TouchListView?

Comment: Is this android:id="@android:id/list" correct? I think correct one is the android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: It appears if i take out the TouchListView. Alternatively, the TouchListView also appears, with no button in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:height="wrap_content"` has no meaning for vertically-scrollable widgets like `ListView`. Use `android:layout_weight` with your `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` to achieve whatever look you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you show an example? I tried specifying the button to be below the list in a Relative Layout, but no luck.

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678284/button-below-a-list-not-showing

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

I'm guessing the layout is just not showing?